# client side Web Scraping through javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I have scraped webpages in java using tagsoup. But I think it is slower when more links are there. So, I thought of scraping through javascript. In googling i found "**pjscrape**" which works with the help of **pyphantomjs** (Which is no longer supported). May i know any other way to scrape web pages (client-side) through java script?

Comment: Why do you think JavaScript would be any faster?

Comment: One of my professors told that, JAVASCRIPT dont need to do all the process which java does in compiling, linking e.t.c... Am I wrong?

Comment: It's true that the compile phase is lighter, but it doesn't have any effect to how fast the program itself runs.

Comment: Time to get a new professor!

Comment: @Juhana: May I know it in depth? I want to learn about it.Will you help me?